# Problem receiving notifications from Trello in my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, trello, notifications

On Trello, I have my notifications set to instantly, but I'm not receiving email updates in my Gmail. Is there a bug or problem I am unaware of?

Comment: Have you checked they aren't ending up in your Spam folder?

Comment: https://trello.com/test_notifications

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue is that you are not subscribed to any cards. Trello does not send email notifications of all changes that are made to your board. Try subscribing to a card, and then ask someone else to comment on that card, and see if you get an email.

More information from their blog: http://blog.trello.com/introducing-subscribe-get-notifications-for-any-card/